What does "ancient anal shit-knot" mean?
In Deadpool & Wolverine (2024), Deadpool introducing Dogpool to Blind Al:

Deadpool: And this little ancient anal
shit-knot is Mary Puppins. Or as I like to call her,
Dogpool.

What does "ancient anal shit-knot" mean?

Funny if you are aged 13

Ancient: old, elderly
Anal: connected with, or originating from, an anus/asshole
Shit-knot: lump of shit [faeces] stuck to hair surrounding the anus.
Altogether a 'funny' toilet-related 'joke' insult invented by the scriptwriters, probably to appeal to the mainly young-teen male audience: what with the gore and the risqué gags, the film earns every last month of its 15 certificate (The Guardian)

What does it mean to "earn every last month of its 15 certificate"?

@TimR - I guess that it means 'goes right up to the limits of an [age] 15 certificate in terms of acceptability', or 'barely suitable for 15 year olds'.

@TimR - Or even (my take, perhaps) 'anyone older than 15 is going to think this film is stupid and unfunny'.

I remember hearing shit-knot when I watched the film, at which time I mentally translated it to the term I've always used - dangleberry. Now it's turned up here, I actually googled my version, and I'm quite impressed to find it's in Merriam-Webster as dingleberry: 3
slang : a piece of dried fecal matter clinging to the hair around the anus
Get over the ick factor and check your pet's rear regularly to make sure no dingleberries are dangling from his fur. I definitely think dangleberry is more appropriate / evocative than dingleberry. I like Deadpool.

@FumbleFingers  I'm not sure if it's because I was brought up to wipe my arse properly, or because mine isn't as hairy as some, but I never experienced the dingleberry in the flesh (so to speak). I remember in the 1990s finding out from Viz magazine that some people (presumably in the North East?) call them 'winnits'. Urban Dictionary gives 'winnet' as an alternative. I gather that Paul McCartney called Slipknot (a rock band) 'Shitknot'.

@FumbleFingers - shitknot - A really badly tangled clump of shit in the anus hairs. Usually occurs when you have long asshole hairs, much worse than dingleberries (Urban Dictionary).

I girl I knew at college used to exclaim Smeggy winnits! in surprise / disgust. She told me a winnit was a dog's penis. I didn't know smeggy at the time, but that was obviously derived from smegma, which I did know. Until today I'd never seen anything to contradict what she told me, which has always stuck in my mind (but I doubt I ever heard anyone else use the word winnit anyway).

dingleberries are usually in reference to cats and dogs, not humans...I don't think it's fair to dv these questions from people.

@Lambie - OED online says 2.b. ?1939– Originally U.S. A particle of faecal matter attached to the hair around the anus of a person or animal. Usually in plural. Also in extended use. My home OED 2nd Ed is shorter but says (appropriately!) ... of an unfastidious person.

@MichaelHarvey I'm not prepared to go into specifics but I have never known of that use in humans. One wonders what their source was.

@Lambie 'Justinian' - Americana sexualis. Compiled and edited by Justinian • 1939.
Chicago: Privately printed.

Ha ha, What a hoot.

This type of humor relies on crude, toilet-related jokes, which I don't consider decent or good humor. It now feels more like a cheap joke, relying on bodily functions for laughs rather than wit or cleverness. Perhaps the younger generation might enjoy such jokes, but it doesn't have much appeal beyond that.
